# I'm trying to build a shopping cart with a remove button that deletes the item each time it is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a shopping cart with a remove button that deletes the item each time the delete is clicked. I've donen this with the filter method. But whenever I do this and add the item another time, the quantity doesn't get deleted and it just updates with the quantity it had before deleting it. When it should giv eme the value of 0 because I've deleted the array.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'

function Cart() {
  const {item, setItem} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)

  const removeItem = (productId) => {
    const newItem = item.filter(i => i.id !== productId)
    const exists = item.findIndex((i) => i.id === productId);
    setItem(newItem)
    setCount(count - item[exists].counts)
  }

    return (
        <div>
          {item.map(({id, img, counts, finalPrice, title}) => (
            <>
            <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>Quantity: {counts}</p>
            <p>Price: {finalPrice}$</p>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(id)}>Remove</button>
            <p></p>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: What's in `useCountsContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are enclosing the `count` state in a bunch of callbacks in a loop you should use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state instead of the state closed over in callback scope. Luckily it's a very simple change.

```
setItem(item => item.filter(i => i.id !== productId));
setCount(count => count - item[exists].counts);
```

Callback code:

```
const removeItem = (productId) => {
  const exists = item.findIndex((i) => i.id === productId);

  setItem(item => item.filter(i => i.id !== productId));
  setCount(count => count - item[exists].counts);
}
```

An optimization would be to also pass along the current element's `counts` value so your callback won't need to search the `items` array each time.

```
const removeItem = (productId, counts) => {
  setItem(item => item.filter(i => i.id !== productId));
  setCount(count => count - counts);
}
```

In the UI

```
<button onClick={() => removeItem(id, counts)}>Remove</button>
```